# In Spring Boot using SimpleThreadScope I get two instances of an object in the same thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, scope

I define an object as with scope "thread".

In some place in the code the instance is obtained with @Autowired and in other place with context getBean(), when comparing the objects, they are different.

Since the object is "thread" scoped I was expecting the same instance of the object to be returned.

Following is the code, first I define a custom scope

```
@Configuration
public class ThreadScopeRegisteringBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.registerScope("thread", new SimpleThreadScope());
    }
}
```

A test object is defined as:

```
@Component
@Scope("thread")
public class ThreadScopeObject implements InitializingBean {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThreadScopeObject.class);

    private String field1;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("****************** new object - " + this);
    }
}
```

Also a service is defined as:

```
@Service
public class ThreadScopeService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThreadScopeService.class);

    @Autowired
    private ThreadScopeObject threadScopeObject;

    public void showObject() {
        LOGGER.info ("ShowObject: " + threadScopeObject);
    }
}
```

And finally a Async method is defined [RunnableService.java]:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Map> objectInstanceTest() {
    ThreadScopeObject o = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(ThreadScopeObject.class);

    LOGGER.info ("Thread object: " + o);

    service.showObject();

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new HashMap<>());
}
```

When running the application I get the following log:

```
19:15:27.094 [mcd-async-1] INFO com.mono.threadSample.ThreadScopeObject - ****************** new object - com.mono.threadSample.ThreadScopeObject@69c8f2bb
19:15:27.094 [mcd-async-1] INFO com.mono.threadSample.RunnableService - Thread object: com.mono.threadSample.ThreadScopeObject@69c8f2bb
19:15:27.094 [mcd-async-1] INFO com.mono.threadSample.ThreadScopeService - ShowObject: com.mono.threadSample.ThreadScopeObject@fd0e5b6
```

I would like to know the reason why an object "thread" scoped is instantiated twice in the same thread.

Code: https://github.com/saavedrah/spring-threadSample

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ThreadScopeService` is a singleton by default, so when it is constructed by spring it will get a `ThreadScopeObject` from the thread that created it and it won't be updated afterwards. There are two ways to solve this:

- inject a `Provider<ThreadScopeObject>` or `ObjectFactory<ThreadScopeObject>` into `ThreadScopeService` and call their `get` methods to retrieve the scoped object when needed.
- annotate the `ThreadScopeObject` with `@Scope("thread", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`. This will make spring create a proxy around your object, which will delegate all calls to the correctly scoped instance.

Comment: I understand your answer, and I fixed my code using the @Scope solution with the proxyMode attribute.However, I'm still thinking that Thread scope should use only one object, the one that was created initially, instead of creating new objects in the same thread. Thank you.